# Choose location of swarms in sns swarmplot

Tags: python, seaborn, swarmplot

I want to show variation of data over time using `sns.swarmplot`. Here is my code:

```
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

y = np.random.randint(5,size = 40)
time = np.repeat([1,2,3,100],10)
sns.swarmplot(time,y)
```

This however interprets the time data as categorical and spreads the swarms evenly.

Is there a way, that the swarms are not evenly spread? That is all points associated with 100 are far more to the right?

Is this solution also applicable to sns.violinplot?

Answer (score 1):

A (not very elegant) solution is to give all categorical datas to `sns.swarmplot`

```
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

y = np.random.randint(5,size = 40)
time = np.repeat([1,2,3,100],10)

# now add more categorical datas
time_all = np.append(time, np.arange(1,101))
y_all = np.append(y, np.nan*np.arange(100))

sns.swarmplot(time_all,y_all)

# hide all the ticks that are not wanted
plt.x_ticks([1,2,3,100],[1,2,3,100])
```